# Wordpress excel plugin export

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, phpspreadsheet

Hello i have try to code my own plugin for wordpress and woocommerce but i have somes little problems : wen the user send the order

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Order to Excel
 * Description: Replaces WooCommerce order emails with an Excel file attachment
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Marin
 * Author URI: monsite.com
 * License: GPL2
 */

 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

 // Ajouter un filtre pour remplacer l'email de commande par un fichier Excel
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'replace_order_email_with_excel', 10, 3 );

function replace_order_email_with_excel( $attachments, $email_id, $order ) {
  if ( 'new_order' === $email_id && $order ) {
    $excel_file = generate_excel_from_order( $order );
    $attachments[] = $excel_file;
  }
  return $attachments;
}

function generate_excel_from_order( $order ) {
  // Répertoire de sauvegarde
  $dir = './backup/';

  // Vérifier si le répertoire existe et est accessible en écriture
  if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    // Répertoire n'existe pas, le créer
    if (!mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
      trigger_error('Impossible de créer le répertoire de sauvegarde', E_USER_WARNING);
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (!is_writable($dir)) {
    // Répertoire n'est pas accessible en écriture
    trigger_error('Répertoire de sauvegarde non accessible en écriture', E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
  }

  $locale = get_locale();
  switch ( $locale ) {
    case 'fr_FR':
      $template_file = 'template-fr.xlsx';
      break;
    case 'zh_CN':
      $template_file = 'template-zh.xlsx';
      break;
    case 'en_US':
    default:
      $template_file = 'template-en.xlsx';
      break;
  }

  // Créer un nouveau classeur
  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
  // Obtenir la première feuille
  $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

  // Définir le numéro de commande
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'G1', $order->get_order_number() );

  // Définir la date de la commande
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'A4', $order->get_date_created()->format( 'Y-m-d' ) );

  // Définir les informations client
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'C4', $order->get_billing_company() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'A5', $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'C5', $order->get_billing_email() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'E5', $order->get_billing_phone() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'G5', $order->get_billing_address_1() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_address_2() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'G6', $order->get_billing_city() . ', ' . $order->get_billing_state() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_postcode() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'G7', $order->get_billing_country() );
  
  // Obtenir les articles de la commande
  $items = $order->get_items();
  $row = 18;
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'B' . $row, $item->get_name() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'H' . $row, $item->get_quantity() );
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'K' . $row, $item->get_total() );
  // Add the serial number
  $sheet->setCellValue( 'G' . $row, get_serial_number( $item ) );
  $row++;
  }
  
  // Enregistrer le fichier Excel
  $file_name = $dir . $order->get_order_number() . '.xlsx';
  $writer = IOFactory::createWriter( $spreadsheet, 'Xlsx' );
  $writer->save( $file_name );
  
  return $file_name;
  }
  
  ?>
```

I have coded a plugin to replace the email received at each order by the woocommerce administrator, I want to replace this email with an excel file generated with the order information using an excel file template that I put in the plugin folder

The problem is that when I place an order I have an error message in front-end as the order does not pass, but I still received a confirmation email but without the excel file.

I tried to debug but without really having any result, do you think my code is a problem?

I already installed the PHPspreadseeet library, manually but also with a plugin : CBX PhpSpreedSheet Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you don't have any **get_serial_number** and here it is:

```
function get_serial_number( $item ) {
  // You can generate the serial number here
  return $serial_number;
}
```

Comment: AR Riyad :  Ah yes i call the value but not the function

Comment: Yes now i can place order but the email is not replace with my excel files is the basic email from woocommerce